# Arduino - switch control

Tags: arduino

I am making a balloon cut off mechanism using Arduino. The Arduino uses GPS data to find the height of the balloon. So when a certain height is reached it has to allow current to pass through a nichrome wire to burn the nylon rope.

How do I use Arduino to act as a switch? That is, when a condition is reached, Arduino has to allow current to pass through. Can it be done using Arduino?

Is there a digital switch I can buy and control via Arduino? My search gave me suggestions to use a Triac. Is there a easier way?

Comment: Why using a triac is not easy enough? Also, for the condition: what's the problem with `while (!condition) { } PORTX != (1 << PIN);`?

Comment: My problem was switching the device using Arduino. Haven't used Triac before. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really a SO question... but I've used this [TIP-120](http://bildr.org/2011/03/high-power-control-with-arduino-and-tip120/) circuit in many projects with success. It's tolerant of abuse (handles high current, etc) and easy to put together with parts from Radio Shack costing a few dollars. (for your usage, the diode is not required).

Turning it on is as simple as `digitalWrite(pinNum, HIGH);`

Personally, I would use a mechanical solution as a [release mechanism](http://diydrones.com/forum/topics/release-mechanism) rather than trusting the vagaries of heating at high altitude and the higher power reqs.

[image]

Comment: Didn't have a TIP-120, but tried it with another transistor. Worked great, now I know how to switch ON something using Arduino. Thanks a LOT. Will look into mechanical options, thanks again for the link.